# The use of the word "startle" in context

Tags: word-choice

Let's say I am creeping up on my friend who is in his chair leaning far back. And then what I do is I tilt his chair way back to make him believe that he is going to fall over just to scare him. Is it natural to use the word *startle* to describe a prank where you scare someone that they are going to fall over? For example:

> I **startled** Mike making him believe that he was going to fall over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Startle" can be used for any small scare.  It could be used to describe such a prank, but it isn't specific to it.

Comment: What would be specific to it?

Comment: "tipping his chair up" or something like that. You don't expect an special word for it, do you?